# How can I reset the filter in VS search?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I do a search in VS (CTRL+SHIFT+F), it saves the filter settings. For example I search for a string only in `*.cs` files, later I want to search again, the filter is there, even though I delete it, it comes back every time. How do I reset the filter?

VS version: 2017 Professional

Comment: Have you tried setting the filter to `*.*`?

Comment: @stuartd no, that might work but I want it to be clear as I opened it for the first time.